# Incrementally Increasing Running Script

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'll lay out the details first and then include everything together at the bottom to ensure I am thorough.

I have a script where I click a table row to bring up the details of that row in a panel to the left. In that panel, there is also a button called Approve Attachment and when clicked, will perform an AJAX POST request to change the record (by changing a field), and update the original table clicked by removing that particular row and altering the count on top.

Specific script:

```
$(document).on("click", ".approveAttachment", function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/equipment/attachments/details/approve',
    data: {
      attachmentID: $(this).data('id'),
      approvalID: 1,
      _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(),
      dataType: 'json',
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data !== undefined) {
        var id = data.details.id;
        var table = $('#unapprovedAttachments');
        table.find('#' + id).hide();
        $('#attachmentDetails').html('');
        var count = $('#attachmentCount').html();
        var newCount = count - 1;
        $('#attachmentCount').html(newCount);
      } else {
        console.log('failed');
        console.log(data);
      }
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('error');
      console.log(data);
    }

  });


});
```

My problem arises in that I have found each time I click the Approve Button, say on the next record or the following or the nth number after that, the number of requests increases by 1. So the first record approved only POSTed once, but the next was approved POSTed twice and continued to increase after that again by 1.

I am not at all sure why and how it is doing this, and is quite aggravating. Below is the "entire page" so I assume if the specific script above isn't causing this, something in the below code is:

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
     <div class="box box-default box-solid">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Attachments Requiring Review (<span id="attachmentCount">{{$attachments->count()}}</span>)</h3>
              <!-- /.box-tools -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
                {{ csrf_field() }} 
              <div style="max-height: 100vh; overflow-y:scroll;">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="unapprovedAttachments">
     <tbody>
            @foreach($attachments as $attachment)
            <tr style="cursor: pointer" class="attachmentView" id="{{$attachment->id}}">
                <td>{{$attachment->id}}<br>
                    @if($attachment->unitID)
                        @if(empty($attachment->equipment->unit_id))
                        No Unit ID
                        @else
                    {{$attachment->equipment->unit_id}}

                        @endif
                    @endif
                </td>
                <td>{{$attachment->attachmentCategory}}<br>@if($attachment->date){{$attachment->date->format('F j, Y')}}@endif</td>
                <td>{{$attachment->vendor}}</td>
                <td><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrow-right"></i></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>

     </table>
</div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>

    </div>

<div class="col-md-9" id="attachmentDetails">


</div>
<script>
    $(document).on("click", ".attachmentView", function(){
            $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: '/equipment/attachments/details/api',
            data: {
                attachmentID: $(this).attr('id'),
                _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                dataType: 'json',
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if(data !== undefined) {
                        $('#attachmentDetails').html('<div class="col-md-8"><div class="box box-default box-solid"><div class="box-header with-border"><h3 class="box-title">Attachment View</h3>      </div><div class="box-body"><div id="viewer" style="height: 600px; width: 100%">                 <object data="'+data.url+'" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"><iframe src="'+data.url+'" style="border: none;" width="100%" height="100%">This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="'+data.url+'">Download PDF</a></iframe></object></div></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><button class="btn btn-primary approveAttachment" data-id="'+data.details.id+'">Approve Attachment</button><div class="box box-default box-solid"><div class="box-header with-border"><h3 class="box-title">Details</h3></div><div class="box-body"><table class="table table-striped table-condensed"><tbody><tr><td><strong>Category</strong></td><td>'+data.details.attachmentCategory+'</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Unit ID</strong></td><td>'+data.equipment.unit_id+'</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Date</strong></td><td>'+data.details.date+'</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Vendor</strong></td><td>'+data.details.vendor+'</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Service ID</strong></td><td>'+data.details.serviceID+'</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Odometer</strong></td><td>'+data.details.odometer+'</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Amount</strong></td><td>'+data.details.amount+'</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Title</strong></td><td>'+data.details.title+'</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Emissions Passed</strong></td><td>'+data.details.emissionsPassed+'</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Emissions Verification No.</strong></td><td>'+data.details.emissionsVerificationNo+'</td></tr><tr><td><strong>File Path</strong></td><td><input class="form-control" name="attachmentPath" value="'+data.details.attachment+'"></td></tr></tbody></table><button class="btn btn-primary updateAttachment" data-id="'+data.details.id+'">Update Attachment</button></div>          </div><div class="box box-default box-solid"><div class="box-header with-border"><h3 class="box-title">Maintenance Details</h3></div><div class="box-body"><table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id="attachmentMaintenanceDetails"><tbody></tbody></table></div></div></div>');
                        $.each(data.maintenance, function(i,val) {
                                    $('<tr>').append(
                                    $('<td>').html(val.maintenanceCategory),
                                    $('<td>').html(val.description)).appendTo('#attachmentMaintenanceDetails');

                            });

                        $(document).on("click", ".updateAttachment", function(){
                            $.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url: '/equipment/attachments/details/update',
                            data: {
                                attachmentID: $(this).data('id'),
                                attachmentPath: $('input[name=attachmentPath]').val(),
                                _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                                dataType: 'json',
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                if(data !== undefined) {
                                        $('#viewer').html('<object data="'+data.url+'" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"><iframe src="'+data.url+'" style="border: none;" width="100%" height="100%">This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="'+data.url+'">Download PDF</a></iframe></object>');
                                    }else{
                                        console.log('failed');
                                        console.log(data);
                                    }
                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                console.log('error');
                                console.log(data);
                            }

                        });


                            });

                    $(document).on("click", ".approveAttachment", function(){
                            $.ajax({
                            type:'POST',
                            url: '/equipment/attachments/details/approve',
                            data: {
                                attachmentID: $(this).data('id'),
                                approvalID: 1,
                                _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                                dataType: 'json',
                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                if(data !== undefined) {
                                        var id = data.details.id;
                                        var table = $('#unapprovedAttachments');
                                        table.find('#'+id).hide();
                                        $('#attachmentDetails').html('');
                                        var count = $('#attachmentCount').html();
                                        var newCount = count - 1;
                                        $('#attachmentCount').html(newCount);
                                    }else{
                                        console.log('failed');
                                        console.log(data);
                                    }
                            },
                            error: function(data) {
                                console.log('error');
                                console.log(data);
                            }

                        });


                            });

                    }else{
                        console.log('failed');
                        console.log(data);
                    }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('error');
                console.log(data);
            }

        });


            });
</script>
```

Comment: it looks like you are hiding the old html and showing the new...but the click handler on the hidden html is possibly still there?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 - I could see that, do you have any suggestions as to where to actually clear it out and only show the current for the active row? Would I use .remove() instead of .hide() on that particular row?

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` should not be inside the `data:` object, it should be in the `$.ajax` options object.

Comment: use remove instead to get it out of the dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you add the click handlers for `.updateAttachment` and `.approveAttachment` inside the AJAX success function of the `.attachmentView` button. So every time you click on that button, you add additional click handlers for the other buttons, causing them to run multiple times.

You should put those click handlers at top level.

```
$(document).on("click", ".attachmentView", function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/equipment/attachments/details/api',
    data: {
      attachmentID: $(this).attr('id'),
      _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(),
      dataType: 'json',
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data !== undefined) {
        $('#attachmentDetails').html('<div class="col-md-8"><div class="box box-default box-solid"><div class="box-header with-border"><h3 class="box-title">Attachment View</h3>      </div><div class="box-body"><div id="viewer" style="height: 600px; width: 100%">                 <object data="' + data.url + '" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"><iframe src="' + data.url + '" style="border: none;" width="100%" height="100%">This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="' + data.url + '">Download PDF</a></iframe></object></div></div></div></div><div class="col-md-4"><button class="btn btn-primary approveAttachment" data-id="' + data.details.id + '">Approve Attachment</button><div class="box box-default box-solid"><div class="box-header with-border"><h3 class="box-title">Details</h3></div><div class="box-body"><table class="table table-striped table-condensed"><tbody><tr><td><strong>Category</strong></td><td>' + data.details.attachmentCategory + '</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Unit ID</strong></td><td>' + data.equipment.unit_id + '</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Date</strong></td><td>' + data.details.date + '</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Vendor</strong></td><td>' + data.details.vendor + '</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Service ID</strong></td><td>' + data.details.serviceID + '</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Odometer</strong></td><td>' + data.details.odometer + '</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Amount</strong></td><td>' + data.details.amount + '</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Title</strong></td><td>' + data.details.title + '</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Emissions Passed</strong></td><td>' + data.details.emissionsPassed + '</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Emissions Verification No.</strong></td><td>' + data.details.emissionsVerificationNo + '</td></tr><tr><td><strong>File Path</strong></td><td><input class="form-control" name="attachmentPath" value="' + data.details.attachment + '"></td></tr></tbody></table><button class="btn btn-primary updateAttachment" data-id="' + data.details.id + '">Update Attachment</button></div>          </div><div class="box box-default box-solid"><div class="box-header with-border"><h3 class="box-title">Maintenance Details</h3></div><div class="box-body"><table class="table table-striped table-condensed" id="attachmentMaintenanceDetails"><tbody></tbody></table></div></div></div>');
        $.each(data.maintenance, function(i, val) {
          $('<tr>').append(
            $('<td>').html(val.maintenanceCategory),
            $('<td>').html(val.description)).appendTo('#attachmentMaintenanceDetails');
        });
      } else {
        console.log('failed');
        console.log(data);
      }
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('error');
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});

$(document).on("click", ".updateAttachment", function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/equipment/attachments/details/update',
    data: {
      attachmentID: $(this).data('id'),
      attachmentPath: $('input[name=attachmentPath]').val(),
      _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(),
      dataType: 'json',
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data !== undefined) {
        $('#viewer').html('<object data="' + data.url + '" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"><iframe src="' + data.url + '" style="border: none;" width="100%" height="100%">This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="' + data.url + '">Download PDF</a></iframe></object>');
      } else {
        console.log('failed');
        console.log(data);
      }
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('error');
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});

$(document).on("click", ".approveAttachment", function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/equipment/attachments/details/approve',
    data: {
      attachmentID: $(this).data('id'),
      approvalID: 1,
      _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(),
      dataType: 'json',
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data !== undefined) {
        var id = data.details.id;
        var table = $('#unapprovedAttachments');
        table.find('#' + id).hide();
        $('#attachmentDetails').html('');
        var count = $('#attachmentCount').html();
        var newCount = count - 1;
        $('#attachmentCount').html(newCount);
      } else {
        console.log('failed');
        console.log(data);
      }
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('error');
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a click handler to `.approveAttachment` elements inside a click handler for `.attachmentView` which is a parent element. So every time an `.approveAttachment` element is clicked the handler for `.attachmentView` will fire and add another click handler for `.approveAttachment`. You need to make sure the click handler for approving is only added once. Try un-nesting your click handlers, like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".attachmentView", function(){
    //...
});
$(document).on("click", ".updateAttachment", function(){
    //...
});
$(document).on("click", ".approveAttachment", function(){
    //...
});
```